# Neo4J set new property on Relationship by Relationship ID

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4J Graph and want to add a new Property on the Relationships based on the `ID` of the Relationship, which is already set. The `ID` is a Property and looks like this:

**id**:16_0beta1_1b500480_1221807483755_439038_8369

In a CSV-File I have stored 400 `IDs` and a `type` corresponding to the `IDs`. Neo4J should load the CSV-File and look through all relationships. When a Relationship `ID` matches an `ID` from the CSV-File it should `set` the new Property like this: `set r.SysML=row.type` and create a new Property on the Relationship:

**SysML**:Block

For the nodes the following clause worked well:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///SysML.csv" AS row 
merge(n:name {id:row.sysID}) 
on match set n.SysML=row.type
```

For Relationship Property i tried:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///SysML.csv" AS row 
merge ()-[r:rel {id:row.sysID}]->() 
on match set r.SysML=row.type
```

I couldn't solve it even with many variations of the relationship...

Comment: This query is correct and should work. You might have missed something in matching query. Could you check if following query returns anything?
`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///SysML.csv" AS row 
MATCH ()-[r:rel {id:row.sysID}]->() 
RETURN r LIMIT 10`

Comment: Yes it returns me all the relationships with the label 'rel' but when i do my query it gives an Error: that Neo4J doesn't like the 'on match set' part...

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

You should NEVER do this:

```
merge ()-[r:rel {id:row.sysID}]->()
```

If the relationship does not already exist, that clause would create a new relationship *between 2 brand new nodes having no labels or properties* (and your `on match` clause would also not be applied).

Since your question indicates you just want to update the `SysML` property of existing `rel` relationships, you should use `MATCH` instead of `MERGE`:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///SysML.csv" AS row 
MATCH ()-[r:rel {id: row.sysID}]->() 
SET r.SysML = row.type
```

By the way, it would be more efficient if you qualified the end nodes (e.g., by supplying labels, or even property values) to avoid having to scan through every relationship in the DB.